# How do you figure out Big O and Big Omega of a Septenary Search?

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime, big-o

For a homework assignment, we're given something called a "Septenary Search" which is like a binary search but instead of halving the data structure, it subdivides it into 7 groups.  We're asked to prove that the worst case runtime is in BigTheta(log n) by writing a recurrence equation and solving it.

Here is the pseudocode for septenary search:

```
septenarySearch(L, s):
  HELPER(L, 0, L.length-1, s)

HELPER(L, Lo, Hi, s):
  if Hi - Lo + 1 > 7:
    basic_group_size = floor((Hi - Lo + 1) / 7)
    number_of_larger_groups = (Hi - Lo + 1) % 7
    for i in 0 .. 6:
      group_size = basic_group_size
      if i < number_of_larger_groups:
        group_size = group_size + 1
      first_element_of_group = i*group_size
      last_element_of_group = (i+1)*group_size - 1
      if L[first_element_of_group] <= s <= L[last_element_of_group]:
        return HELPER(L, first_element_of_group, last_element_of_group, s)
  else:
    for index in Lo .. Hi:
    if s == L[index]:
      return true
    return false
```

We were also given a hint that the number of elements considered
in the recursive call to HELPER is at least 1/7 of those in the range (between Lo and Hi) passed in, and the number is no more than 1/4 of them.

I'm pretty sure one of the recurrence equations is `T(n) = c + T(n/7)` where `c` is some constant value and I think that gets me BigO(log n). If I'm trying to prove Big Theta, I need to prove BigOmega(log n) as well, correct?  How do I find what BigOmega is?

I'm sure the 1/4 is supposed to be used to find BigOmega, but not sure how to do this (or even where the 1/4 came from).

Answer (score 0):

Hints given:

```
Number of elements in recursive call >= n/7                     (+)
Number of elements in recursive call <= n/4                     (++)
```

Hence, a lower and upper bound on the running time of the algorithm are given by

```
Lower bound: 
Assume all recursive calls contains n/7 number of elements from
range passed to previous call call (n elements). 
Recurrence relation: 

     T_L(n) = T(n/7) + c                                        (i)

Upper bound: 
Assume all recursive calls contains n/4 number of elements from
range passed to previous call call (n elements). 
Recurrence relation:  

     T_U(n) = T(n/4) + c                                        (ii)
```

You can solve `(i)` and `(ii)` by unrolling the recursion, which will give you Big-Θ relations directly:

[image]

Now you're asked about the worst case complexity, in which case `T(n) = T_U(n)`. Hence, worst case is `T(n) ∈ Θ(log_4 n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what this algorithm does is:

1. Get a sorted list `L` of size `n`
2. split it into 7 sub lists of size `n/7` to `n/7 + 1`
3. check in which sub list your element could possible be.
4. run the algorithm recursively on this sub list.

So the recurrence relation is at best

```
T(n)  = T(n/7) + c
```

and the worst case is

```
T(n) = T(n/7 + 1) + c  ≤  T(n/4) + c
```

The 1/4 comes from minimizing `d` in `floor(n/7) + 1 = n/d` with `n > 7` and `n mod 7 ≠ 0`. It is minimized for `n = 8` and yields `d = 4`.

You can now use the [masters theorem](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master-Theorem) to solve this.

This leads to `T(n) ∈ Θ(log n)` for each best and worst case (since constant factors like different log basis is ignored)